# WPF MediaKit buffering progress

Tags: wpf-mediakit

Is it possible to get notified when WPF MediaKit's MediaUriElement starts buffering video from internet (i.e. Source="http://example.com/vid.mp4). 
Standard MediaElement component has property BufferingProperty whereas MediaKit's one seems doesn't have something like that. 
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP streaming and file (URL) handling in general is the task of the codecs, so the WPF MediaKit does not access it. When the `MediaOpened` event fires, then at least the some bytes from HTTP has been read, since the codecs must read the video metadata to build the graph. So I would assume this as start of the buffering.

Note: Maybe some codecs may provide some API to get more details about buffering, but I do not know about it.

Comment: thanks I should probably look into that direction :D